# Python reading from excel: AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Tags: python, excel, tuples

I'm just getting into Python and am trying to write a script which prints a cell from a excel work book. I've got an input which I want to add 2 to the value so it finds the right cell. Just having a problem when I put the variable into the index. Could you help please?

I've tried looking at the other examples with the same callback but none answer the question.

```
import openpyxl
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('kids.xlsx')
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

print("Type index of student")
find_student  = input()
val = int(find_student)
proper_index = val + 2
print(proper_index)

string_value = str(proper_index)
index_search = "'A" + string_value + "'"
print(index_search)



print(sheet[string_value].value)
```

Thanks

Comment: When I change the code to:  print(sheet['A3'].value) it returns the right value

Comment: Try removing the " ' " when you generate your string.

Comment: tried that just now, when i run the code, i type in 1, string_value now returns A3 but I get the reply print(sheet[string_value].value)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: Next thing would be" dir(sheet[string_value])" and" type(sheet[string_value])". Just to see what method are possible. The method you are calling with [ _ ] is this one: def __getitem__(self, key): """Convenience access by Excel style coordinates         The key can be a single cell coordinate 'A1', a range of cells 'A1:D25',         individual rows or columns 'A', 4 or ranges of rows or columns 'A:D',         4:10.         Single cells will always be created if they do not exist.         Returns either a single cell or a tuple of rows or columns.         """

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/src/87153d1598b5fc7692472d20ec2b6ef153ddf478/openpyxl/worksheet/worksheet.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha...solved it

```
#access cell data

let_us_see = ws.cell(row=proper_index, column=1).value
print(let_us_see)
```

Instead of using: print(sheet[string_value].value)  i looked on the openpyxl forum which suggested another way of accessing the value from the cell. The above code accepts the integer value of proper_index!

Thanks for all your help dudes and dudettes.

Answer (score 0):

If answer still applies, `sheet[string_value]` always returns a tuple of cells. Hence you have to choose, which cell you want, even if it gives you only a singleton tuple:

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('kids.xlsx')
sheet = wb["Sheet1"]

print("Type index of student")
val = int(
    input()
)

proper_index = val + 2
print(proper_index)

index_search = "A%s"%(proper_index,)
print(index_search)

print(sheet[string_value][0].value)
```

PS: Sorry for being a bit late.

Comment: Never too late for a little extra knowledge, thanks.